# Network disconnection on locking the the windows. (WIN+L)

Tags: windows-7

Wherever I lock my system, the network (WIRED LAN) disconnects automatically. When I unlock it, only then it connects back. So, while in locked state, all the processes (which are using network) like Outlook, Chat messenger (Lync) goes offline.

Answer (score 7):

Change your Network Card Power Saving Settings. Go to

> Start > Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings

Select your Wired Lan Adapter Properties. In the power management tab
Uncheck **"Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"**

You can change advance power saving settings from Power Options in Control Panel.